# VS2017 Architecture Code Map generation Error Symbol name is null

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-map

I wanted to try the Code Map generation functionality out in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise on one of the projects that I'm working on. The result is a "Error Symbol name is null" on a "Error information" page with an empty "Call Stack".
[image: Code Map generation error]
I have tried repairing the VS installation and also modifying the installed components through the VS installer but to no succes. The generation seems to stop for a while at "Connecting to code index" and at "Indexing the code: Processing files... (1 of 2)" it starts returning transaction errors which presumably have to do with the "Connecting to code index"(?). I don't make use of a database in this project.
[image]
Do I require to run a SQL server on the same machine as this functionality is used? I have tried "Code Map" generation on the same project but on a different machine a while ago and back then it worked fine. Generating a "Code Map" on a far smaller project (a new solution generated project) works fine on this system.

Comment: I encounter to this error when generate code map for QT with C++,have you known how to solve it?

Comment: @Crawl.W sorry, no. This is still unresolved. I haven't used the function since, and have moved to Resharpers architecture function.

Comment: Can Can Resharpers generate funcational call graph for C++?

Comment: It's only project dependency diagrams, so, no. It's not as good as the VS functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem,although I have not solved this way.(I wanna generate call graph in Qt with C++).I read from [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2017)

that **Architecture Code Map generation** need compilation information,such as .pdb file E.g.I think you may encounter a problem with the file path or elements.And I tossed up and got residual(partial) graph.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve it at your end. I'm not sure if this would help with the problem that I had. I can't test this anymore but I'm pretty sure that I have tried to delete my bin and obj folder to cleanly recompile the project for this kind of problems.